# Character representation of bytes greater then 0x75 (127)

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get a character/string encoding of bytes greater then 0x7F in c#

At the moment i get 0x3f (?) from any of these bytes greater then 0x7F and i imagine that's an error character because there is no corresponding character.

I need to build a byte[] and unfortunately(due to code structure i cant control) this must be passed around my program as a string each character representing a byte. My byte[] needs some of its bytes to be greater then 0x7F but the string cant handle these characters. The values to be encoded to characters are just ints nothing special but are in the range 0-255.

Example:

say i want my byte[] to be 3 bytes {0x2E, 0x55, 0x8D}

I want my string representation of this to be to be something like ".U\x8D"
but instead i get ".U?" which translates to an incorrect byte array

Comment: where you get it? reading from db? reading from file? in visual studio? when printing? It would be best to post some sample code

Comment: @Uriel_SVK i get it from `Chr.ConvertFromUtf32(0x8d)` wich i hope would return a encoding for a character but it returns the character ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with the 33% storage overhead, the simplest solution seems to be Base64 encoding:

```
byte[] bytes = {0x2e, 0x55, 0x8d};
string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
byte[] bytes2 = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if it is possible to make it the way you would like. String is a representation of unicode characters. Unicode `0x8d` is `REVERSE LINE FEED`, so in string its represented with `?`. The same goes for other control characters(like 0x01, 0x02, ...)

If you have to send it like string you can try coma separated list of characters(`1,2,141,255`), it might be the best solution for your problem.